# Jenkins - copy artifact from parent job only

Tags: jenkins

I have a multi-module Maven project like this:

```
Parent_Project
    Module_A
    Module_B
    Module_C
```

I have a Jenkins job that builds the project and archives some artifacts using an `Archive the artifacts` post-build action.

I have a second Jenkins job where I want to copy one of the archived artifacts using the `Copy artifacts from another project` build step.

Now, if I configure it like this in Jenkins:

```
#Copy artifacts from another project
Project name: PARENT_PROJECT
```

i receive the following warning:

> Artifacts will be copied from all modules of this Maven project;
>   click the help icon to learn about selecting a particular module.

... and Jenkins will indeed loop through all the modules, including the parent project and eventually find the artifact.

But is there a way to configure Jenkins to ONLY look for the archived artifacts in the parent project (and ignore artifacts from the modules)?